# Rewrite data in loop XForms 1.1

Tags: xforms

I need to rewrite data from one model to the other. Both models have different namespaces e.g.

```
<xf:instance id="mainDoc1">
    <doc1:Document>
        <doc1:User>name1</doc1:User>
        <doc1:User>name2</doc1:User>
        ...
        <doc1:User>nameN</doc1:User>
    </doc1:Document>
    ...
 </xf:instance>

 <xf:instance id="mainDoc2">
    <doc2:Document>
        <doc1:User/>
    </doc2:Document>
    ...
 </xf:instance>
```

When I press
the button (trigger) on the form data are reading from `mainDoc1` (this functionality is done) but now I need to write some data to instance `mainDoc2`. I need some loop for `doc1:Document` because I don't know how many `doc1:User` elements there can be.

All this should be done in same trigger which reading data for `mainDoc1`.

Answer (score 0):

You do this with the `xf:insert` action. You don't need to loop because the action is able to copy over more than one XML node at a time:

```
<xf:trigger>
    <xf:label>Do it!</xf:label>
    <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
        <xf:insert
            context="instance('mainDoc2')"
            ref="*"
            origin="instance('mainDoc1')/doc1:User"/>
    </xf:action>
</xf:trigger>
```

Explanation:

- the `context` attribute means "insert into" this element
- the `ref` attribute means "insert next to" these elements
- the `origin` attribute means "these are the nodes to copy"

The combination of `context` and `ref` makes it so that if `instance('mainDoc2')` doesn't contain children element, the origin elements will be inserted into it, and if it does contain children elements, they will be inserted after the last one.